# vBulletin, something is overiding my div positioning and the code is no where

Tags: html, positioning, vbulletin

ok so i have vbulletin and the product http://www.vbulletin.org/forum/showthread.php?t=204517 install, i have it set so the search bar is located in my fixed navigation bar. it all works ok except the box that is called with search results will not follow my nav bar no matter what.  I have tried surrounding the template in its own div, putting style="position:fixed !important;" in a billion different places, and have even tried other methods to no avail.

it looks good, but when i scroll the page it stays where it loaded like it wont scroll with the page, so i looked at the source in firefox to see how it was reading it and i see..

```
<!-- [AJAX] Live Search -->
 <div id="lsa_window_menu" class="vbmenu_popup" style="margin-top: 37px; position: absolute; width: 400px; z-index: 50; clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, auto); left: 759.5px; top: 12.5px;" multilinks-noscroll="true">
```

its reading as position absolute and has some other styling that's not even in the template.

that line in my template looks like:

```
<!-- [AJAX] Live Search -->
    <div id="lsa_window_menu" class="vbmenu_popup" style="margin-top: 37px; position: fixed !important; width: $vboptions[lsa_width];">
```

so i decided to find every instance of lsa_window_menu in every template and every outside file that came with the product and same with vbmenu_popup, and even checked that $vboptions[lsa_width] option cause the option could have been what was doing it, but no where is anything making the position absolute nor anything that says multilinks-noscroll, so I'm at a loss.

what could possibly be forcing that pacific element to be forced absolute, i have looked up and down for an answer, and wrapping it with another div or anything giving it the fixed position just makes it vanish all together.  the only thing im not too good with reading is the js and i honestly have no idea if thats what could be doing it.

so how can i fix this, what could be causing this?

here are all the files in this mod, the problem should be somewhere in here cause i get the same result no matter what skin i use, i can provide a live demo if needed =)
[Files](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1k4nmjsa4mwn47l/%5BYUI%5D%20Live%20Search%20v3.0.2%20En.zip)

Comment: changing that absolute from within firefox's inspector fixes this issue, the problem is that absolute does not exist! i have no idea whats causing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by simply adding:

```
#lsa_window_menu{
position: fixed !important;
top: 50px !important;
}
```

to my css cant believe i didnt think of that sooner ><  but i still never found out where that position absolute was ever coming from, but oh well =)